# Why did holder.imageview.getContext() return TintContextWrapper in recyclerview？

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-imageview, android-context

I have a RecyclerView, there is an ImageView in the ViewHolder.

The RecyclerView is in a fragment which is attached on an Activity.
When onCreateViewHolder called `parent.getContext()` return MainActivity.
But when OnBindViewHolder called `holder.imageview.getContext()` return TintContextWrapper.

why?

here is my code.

```
    @Override
    public AbsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Log.i(TAG, "parent context : " + parent.getContext());
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(
                    parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list_linear_layout_item, parent,
                    false));
        return holder;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your ImageView using `android:tint` or other compatible attributes?

`Tint` is [added in API 21](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList)). And provides compatibility in android support v7 [TintContextWrapper](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/4ab820f/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/internal/widget/TintContextWrapper.java).

As this code done, it wrap the context to `TintContextWrapper` to support TintResources. Refer to [this example](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintContextWrapper), It seems the android-support-v7 library also does something like this when compatible view created:

```
public class TintContextWrapper extends ContextWrapper {
    public static Context wrap(Context context) {
        if (!(context instanceof TintContextWrapper)) {
            context = new TintContextWrapper(context);
        }
        return context;
    }
//...
}
```

In somewhere, your activity will be replaced with `TintContextWrapper`.

As long as you using support library, compiler will use  [AppCompatImageView](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageView.java) automatically instead of `ImageView`.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! In my xml code, I didn't use android:tint or other compatible attributes here. I will check my java code. And Thanks for your formating, I'm new in stackoverflow.

Comment: Are you using any android support library? like `support-v4` or `appcompat-v7`. if so, the compiler will use the compat one automatically

Comment: Yes, I uesd both support-v4 and appcompat-v7. What do you mean is that as long as I use a support library, no matter whether I use a tint attribute or not, it will wrap ImageView's context to TintContextWrapper?

Comment: You can log your `ImageView` instance in runtime. It is not `ImageView` but `AppCompatImageView`. So it will be wrapped.

Comment: If this problem troubles you when getting own activity, I suggest just pass your activity in adapter constructor.  Anyway, the `getContext()` return type is not reliable.